# What is the Chinese hypersonic capability? (supersonic test orbited the Earth in August, long march rocket & JF22 supersonic wind tunnel)

Tags: china, long-march, supersonic

Current news cycle is reporting the Chinese supersonic missile capable rocket that orbited earth in August. The various news reports are extremely light on details.

Some info on the long march series.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_March_(rocket_family)#Long_March_8
https://www.primidi.com/long_march_rocket_family/specifications_of_long_march_rocket_family

The JF22 supersonic wind tunnel was reported in June & August.
https://eurasiantimes.com/30-times-faster-than-speed-of-sound-is-china-really-wining-the-hypersonic-race-with-its-jf-22-wind-tunnel/
"The JF-22, for example, uses chemical explosions to create hypersonic conditions in the tunnel unlike facilities in other countries, which use mechanical compressors to generate high-speed airflow.

https://www.janes.com/defence-news/news-detail/chinas-new-hypersonic-wind-tunnel-expected-to-be-ready-next-year

"China's new JF-22 hypersonic wind tunnel is expected to be ready for use in 2022, according to a 22 August report by state broadcaster China Central Television (CCTV).

The report confirmed that the wind tunnel has been designed to be capable of simulating conditions for vehicles travelling at speeds of up to Mach 30 at altitudes between 40 km and 100 km."

https://www.hngn.com/articles/237442/20210824/china-threatens-west-hypersonic-wind-tunnel-develops-worlds-fastest-missiles.htm
"The SCMP said that the tunnel could simulate an impossible Mach 30, which is incredible speed. A capability that threatens the West with Hypersonic wind tunnels to forward their technology."

older news reveals coverage back in 2017.
https://www.scmp.com/news/china/policies-politics/article/2120072/china-builds-worlds-fastest-wind-tunnel-test-weapons

**edit:** there might be some info buried in previous announcement on the official Chinese national space administration site. Even the CCP likes to brag sometimes. The 'wind' tunnel announcements provided some hint of capabilities.

http://www.cnsa.gov.cn/english/index.html

Comment: None of the sources you have linked to are in any way reliable, rating between hearsay and propaganda. I suspect nobody here knows as it's bound to be a closely held state secret.

Comment: "supersonic/hypersonic" and "orbit" belong to different realms. If you told me that somebody was developing a hypersonic missile, I would assume that you meant a cruise missile that flies through the atmosphere at hypersonic speeds. If you told me about an orbital or sub-orbital flight, then I would assume that it followed a mostly ballistic trajectory, and mostly above the atmosphere.

Comment: `+1` I was going to ask about this at some point but you beat me to it! As you point out "the various news reports are extremely light on details". At some point if no answers are forthcoming here, you might consider flagging a moderator and seeing about migrating to [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) where the community knowledgable about powered flight in low pressure (trans-Karman) may be much larger.

Comment: uhoh : yeah, I was a bit hesitant to ask as I couldn't find any previous questions or (as GgD pointed out) any credible sources. (hence the phrasing of the question) Hopefully someone will shed some insight with a credible source instead of being toxic.

Comment: uhoh : just saw your edit question suggestion: I'll have a think on how to rephrase the question and update in 24hrs. at moment I'm hoping the current wording will flush out some input.  For example : The 'wind tunnel' capacity would provide some insight to flight speed capability.